# How to download multiple files with for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm stuck on what should be a fairly simple problem. But I'm a beginner coder so it's not obvious to me. 
I'm trying to download images from a website using dynamic names. I think what happens is that I'm overwriting the same file over and over again or that I'm only downloading the last file (America's favourite sports). It works if I hardcode the file name or limit the download to only one file, but that's not the point obviously. Otherwise I get an error saying: `No such file or directory: 'C:\\My File Path\\Images\\John Wick: Chapter 1.jpg'`
Can someone point me into the right direction please?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://public.tableau.com/en-gb/gallery/?tab=viz-of-the-day&type=viz-of-the-day")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

vizzes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gallery-items-list 
div.gallery-list-item-container")))
for viz in vizzes:

    #name of the viz
    viz_name = viz.find_element_by_class_name("gallery-list-item-title-left").text

    #get image links
    images = viz.find_element_by_xpath(".//img[@data-test-id='galleryListItem-thumbnail-image']")
    image_link = images.get_attribute("src")

    #download images 
    myfile = requests.get(image_link)

    with open("C:\My File Path\Images" + "\\" + viz_name + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
            f.write(myfile.content)

time.sleep(5)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Certain characters can't go in file names. Problem is, any character can go in a title.**

You can't have colons (:), you can't have question marks (?), you can't have spaces, etc. The problem is, your titles have all of these things. You need a function to convert your titles to names which can be properly used as file names.

Here is the function I used:

```
def valid_file_name(name):
    return name.replace(" ", "_").replace("?","").replace(":","")
```

Here is where I put it:

```
    with open("C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Pictures\\dumping" + "\\" + valid_file_name(viz_name) + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
            f.write(myfile.content)
```

The full and complete code is below and it works for me. Make sure to change the image folder to the one you want to use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def valid_file_name(name):
    return name.replace(" ", "_").replace("?","").replace(":","")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://public.tableau.com/en-gb/gallery/?tab=viz-of-the-day&type=viz-of-the-day")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

vizzes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gallery-items-list div.gallery-list-item-container")))
for viz in vizzes:

    #name of the viz
    viz_name = viz.find_element_by_class_name("gallery-list-item-title-left").text

    #get image links
    images = viz.find_element_by_xpath(".//img[@data-test-id='galleryListItem-thumbnail-image']")
    image_link = images.get_attribute("src")

    #download images
    myfile = requests.get(image_link)

    print(valid_file_name(viz_name))
    with open("C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Pictures\\dumping" + "\\" + valid_file_name(viz_name) + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
            f.write(myfile.content)

time.sleep(5)

driver.close()
```